# Doubts about rate and samples/channel in ConfigureSampleClock

Tags: c#, nidaqmx

I have certain doubts about how to configure the samples/channel at a determinate rate for a continuous acquisition using the NIDAQmx library in Visual Studio C#.
I am acquiring 5 analog channels using the NI USB-6212 board. I want to acquire at a 200Hz per channel rate, so the total acquisition rate should be 1200 Hz (200Hz per channel)?, or the rate specified at `ConfigureSampleClock` method is per channel (1200Hz per channel)? There is no specification for this.

````
myTask.AIChannels.CreateVoltageChannel("dev1/ai0:4", "", AITerminalConfiguration.Rse,
    minValue, maxValue, AIVoltageUnits.Volts);```

myTask.Timing.ConfigureSampleClock("", rate, SampleClockActiveEdge.Rising,
    SampleQuantityMode.ContinuousSamples, sampleperchannel);```
````

Also, what should be the relation between `rate` and `sampleperchannel`?

Answer (score 1):

For the `SampleQuantityMode.ContinuousSamples` mode, `samplesPerChannel` is a size of a per-channel buffer: [docs](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370473J-01/ninetdaqmxfx40ref/html/m_nationalinstruments_daqmx_timing_configuresampleclock_1/).
It should be sufficient to hold at least [`myTask.EveryNSamplesReadEventInterval`](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370473J-01/ninetdaqmxfx40ref/html/p_nationalinstruments_daqmx_task_everynsamplesreadeventinterval/) samples, which you get in the [`EveryNSamplesRead`](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370473J-01/ninetdaqmxfx40ref/html/e_nationalinstruments_daqmx_task_everynsamplesread/) event handler.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I have read that, but my doubts are with the relation between both parameters (rate and samplesperchannel), right now I have de same value for both, and the program works fine, but if i set samplesperchannel 10 times lower than rate it works fine also. So, I really do not see any difference. On the other hand, I have acquired the samples for the 5 channels with the rate=200 and I receive the amount corresponding to a 200 Hz/channel rate, I always asumed that in order to acomplish that rate/channel I had to multiply rate five times (as there are 5 channels in my example)